# JS How to use reduce on array containing multiple numerical values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array like this.

```
[{
    PropertyOne : 1,
    PropertyTwo : 5
},
{
    PropertyOne : 3,
    PropertyTwo : 5
},...]
```

And I want to end up with an array like this which aggregates all the columns of this array to end up like this.

```
[{
    PropertyOne : 4,
    PropertyTwo : 10
}}
```

If it was a single column I know I could use .reduce but can't see how I could do with multiple columns ?

Comment: how you getting PropertyOne :6 ?

Comment: You have access to the full object in your reduce callback. Accumulate against each property and return the full object.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `PropertyOne: 3` since `1 + 2 = 3`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var array = [{
  PropertyOne : 1,
  PropertyTwo : 5
},
{
  PropertyOne : 2,
  PropertyTwo : 5
}];
var reducedArray = array.reduce(function(accumulator, item) {
  // loop over each item in the array
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
    // loop over each key in the array item, and add its value to the accumulator.  don't forget to initialize the accumulator field if it's not
    accumulator[key] = (accumulator[key] || 0) + item[key];
  });

  return accumulator;
}, {});
```

Comment: You can just wrap this in an array to get what you ask for specifically in your question (array of one object)

Comment: @ExplosionPills , good point!  I missed that. `var reducedArray = [array.reduce( /*... */ )];`

Answer (score 7):

The same (as other answers) using ES6 arrow functions:

```js
    var reducedArray = array.reduce((accumulator, item) => {
      Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
        accumulator[key] = (accumulator[key] || 0) + item[key];
      });
      return accumulator;
    }, {});
```

Comment: You could also wrap the accumulator with
.
`if (typeof item[key] === 'number') { ....
     accumulatory[key]....
}`